# How do I profile a SQL CLR application?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR function in SQL Server 2005.  I want to profile this function to make sure there are no memory leaks.  Any recommendations on how to determine if my function is behaving properly?

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks are atypical for CLR applications, so that should be of little concern. But if I were to profile a SQL CLR function, I think I would create a stand-alone test application that calls the same DLL/methods outside of SQL Server and profile that. It seems to me that SQL's own resource use would swamp most performance affects of your own methods when run in that environment. But I have never tried such a thing myself.